# Get current URL inside ajax callback?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have created custom module called `mymodule`.

In this URL **localhost/mymodule/name**, I have this field:

```
$form['name'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Enter name'),
  ...
  '#ajax' => array(
    'event' => 'blur',
    'callback' => 'mymodule_ajax_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'my-wrapper',
    'method' => 'replace',
  ),
  ...
);
```

My ajax callback is successfully called:

```
function mymodule_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  ...
  return ...
}
```

However, inside 'mymodule_ajax_callback', I need to get the current URL of the page which is **localhost/mymodule/name**. Currently it returns **system/ajax** which is how Drupal works by nature.

How to get the current URL inside the ajax callback?

Comment: You can save the current url in session when your page is render and can use the same in 'mymodule_ajax_callback'.

Comment: You can get it from `$form['#action']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said by @Jayendra Kainthola 
You need to store current path value in a session

```
$_SESSION['current_path'] = current_path();
```

Then use it inside your callback function as follows :

```
function mymodule_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state) {

$current_path = $_SESSION['current_path']  ;//gives the current path

}
```

Comment: Note that this disables page caching.

Answer (score 1):

**$form['#action']** can be used in order to meet the requirement of the **Url**. And then used as one want.

```
$form['#action']
```

Like:

```
function xyz_ajax_function($form, &$form_state){
  if(strpos($form['#action'], YOUR_URL_WANT_TO_CHECK)){
    echo 'yes';
  }else{
    echo 'no';
  }
}
```