# Should drupal_is_front_page work with ajax and a panelized front page?

Tags: views

I have a panelized front page which is accessible via base_url/home or base_url/.

If I call the front page normally drupal_is_front_page returns TRUE, but if I use a view with an exposed filter using ajax, drupal_is_front_page returns FALSE. The question is, is this a normal behaviour, or might there be a module or some custom code, which leads to this result?

If I follow the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7) of this function and check

```
$_GET['q'] == variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node')
```

this always leads to a TRUE, even if I use an exposed filter with ajax. So maybe drupal_static() delivers a wrong result...

My project is developed now over a few months and I think there had been times where this didn't occur, but I am not 100% sure. And if this is not the normal behaviour, how could I detect the code responsible for this behaviour?

Comment: It's normal - the path for AJAX requests is `system/ajax`, which isn't the front page

Comment: Yes from my personal understanding I would agree to this, so what is the alternative? Using $_GET['q'] == variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node') for an exposed filter using ajax?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86939/get-current-url-inside-ajax-callback has a couple of ideas